# How do I make Ruby 1.9 the default Ruby on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ruby-1.9

Is there any way, on Ubuntu 9.04, to install Ruby 1.8 as `ruby1.8` (or get rid of it altogether) and have Ruby 1.9 be the default `ruby`?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I'm not really sure, but maybe this can help:

```
update-alternatives --config ruby
```

... and here's the non-interactive, scriptable, way:

```
update-alternatives --set ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
```

You may find out about available alternatives and respective `/usr/bin/...` paths by doing:

```
update-alternatives --query ruby
```

Comment: thanks, didn't work out of the box but searching for `update-alternatives ruby` brought up http://krnjevic.com/wp/?p=209 which has a howto

Comment: The correct way of dealing with this is to use RVM, as linked by henry74. Messing with Ubuntu directly is strongly discouraged, as it will increase your headaches later.

Comment: Using RVM isn't the "correct way", it's "a way". Installing a local Ruby in `/usr/local/bin` is the standard way, with an adjustment to the path to search `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`

Comment: Also important to switch your gem version: `sudo update-alternatives --set gem /usr/bin/gem1.9.1`

Comment: `update-alternatives` shows "no alternative for ruby"?

Comment: @richardkmiller: even better, set the gem version as `--slave` of the ruby version, as shown in the blog post.

Answer (score 6):

Martin - Take a look at the following link: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

This is where installation of ruby is heading for ubuntu servers. This should allow you to not only switch to a ruby version when needed, but also keep gems separated based on ruby versions, etc.

Comment: thanks - i have indeed switched to rvm and find it very pleasant to work with.

Answer (score 3):

You can completely remove Ruby 1.8 too with:

```
sudo apt-get remove libruby1.8 ruby1.8 ruby1.8-dev rubygems1.8
```

After that, you will only have Ruby 1.9 installed.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --rails
```

will install an up-to-date version of ruby (and rails), and allow you to avoid brokenness of Ubuntu's RVM, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756.

If you go this route, get rid of Ubuntu-installed versions and associated packages like `bundle`.

Details here: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

(Note: this is the TL;DR version of the post by henry74.)

Comment: oh yeah, i definitely installed it myself. every time i've tried to install language-specific package managers via the system package manager, either on arch or on ubuntu, i've ended up regretting it.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1 rubygems1.9.1
```

or try building from source. this worked for me on ubuntu 9.04 and after a restart 1.9 was the standard ruby

Comment: i got it working via update-alternatives, as described here: http://krnjevic.com/wp/?p=209

Comment: I don't see what you're getting at - I installed and rebooted. You can install ruby1.9 either from the source, or via repository. This was the expected behaviour. I didn't sit down and mumble voodoo chants while feverishly typing in commands I thought looked pretty.