# Heroku Toolbelt requires Ruby 1.9+

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, heroku

During the Heroku login in the terminal I get the message:

```
Heroku Toolbelt requires Ruby 1.9+
```

I'm using Vagrant, while in Vagrant I ran `which ruby`  command and got: `/usr/bin/ruby`, and `ruby -v` gives me:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
```

Running `which ruby` command in bash gives me:

```
/usr/local/rbenv/shims/ruby
```

and `ruby -v` gives me:

```
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

So it seems like I have to update the Mac OSX version to 1.9+, but I'm not sure how. Also, I don't believe I have **rvm** installed. I'm new to all this and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You have that reversed.  You have ruby-2.1.0 on the Mac and ruby-1.8.7 within Vagrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant is a virtual machine, which will host a completely different environment to your current machine.

You need to log in to the Vagrant box, and upgrade `ruby` inside the Vagrant container.

You can either do this [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403278/how-to-update-ruby-on-linux-ubuntu), with [`RVM`](https://jibai31.wordpress.com/2013/09/01/upgrading-your-vagrant-box-to-ruby-20/) or with [`rbenv`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). As a first port of call try `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3` inside the Vagrant vm.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you! I actually figured it out shortly after I posted this and it is just as you explain it. I had to install rvm in Vagrant, then update ruby in Vagrant. It was easy enough once I found the right information, but sometimes as your beginning these things can be confusing. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that rvm worked for you - it's a useful tool. Don't forget to mark the question as 'accepted' if you're happy with the answer. Thanks for joining stackoverflow!